# Design pattern(Java): Multiple classes, same field set

Tags: java, design-patterns

Consider a Java program that includes 3 classes: `Entry`, `Validator`, and `Context`. `Validator` has a method `boolean isValid(Entry entry, Context context)`, which will determine the validity of an entry object based on a context. Validator can either be set to check each `entry.field` against a preset specific value (i.e. `MatchingMode.SPECIFIC`) or against the value of the corresponding field from Context (i.e. `MatchingMode.CONTEXT`). `MatchingMode` is a nested enum within `Validator` class. Consider the following pseudo code for further elaboration:

```
Validator::boolean isValid(Entry entry, Context context)
{
    boolean valid = true;
    for(each field):
        if(this.field.matchingMode == MatchingMode.SPECIFIC)
            valid &= (entry.field.equals(this.field));
        else if(this.field.matchingMode == MatchingMode.CONTEXT)
            valid &= (entry.field.euqals(context.field));
    return valid;
}
```

**Notes:**

- All validator objects are created in the beginning of the code's execution and will persist until its termination.
- Entries are user's input to the program and will continually be fed to the code.
- Context objects will be created based on the entries.
- Fields have different types.

Given the above validation use case, how do you suggest implementing this code in a DRY and type-safe manner?

**Edit 1:**

The logic to validate each and every field is the same. Take a look at the current live code(simplified to make sense as an example):

```
class Validator
{
    int field1;
    MatchingMode field1MM;

    String field2;
    MatchingMode field2MM;

    // and a few more filed/MMs

    boolean isValid(Entry entry, Context context)
    {
        boolean valid = true;
        if(this.field1MM == MatchingMode.SPECIFIC)
            valid &= (entry.field1.equals(this.field1));
        else if(this.field1MM == MatchingMode.CONTEXT)
            valid &= (entry.field1.euqals(context.field1));

        if(this.field2MM == MatchingMode.SPECIFIC)
            valid &= (entry.field2.equals(this.field2));
        else if(this.field2MM == MatchingMode.CONTEXT)
            valid &= (entry.field2.euqals(context.field2));

        // copy and paste for each field/MM

        return valid;
    }
}
```

The maintenance overhead to only add/remove 1 field just does not feel right:

- Add/remove the field from 3 classes
- Add/remove fieldMM field to the validator
- Copy/delete the 4-line-long validation for the field

Is there really no better way of doing this kind of validation?

Comment: One small improvement would be to change the fields that you validate against into a separate context. With that change you only need one if at the top which decides if the passed context or the internal context should be used

Comment: @Absurd-Mind validator instances need to determine whether they should use the internal or passed context for each field. Correct me if I'm wrong but creating that context would still need the ifs for each field, only in a higher level in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to create a helper method which takes over the ugly part:

```
<T> boolean contextualEquals(T entryValue, T validatorValue, T contextValue, MatchinMode mode) {
    if (mode == SPECIFIC) {
        return Objects.equals(entryValue, validatorValue);
    }
    return Objects.equals(entryValue, contextValue);
}
```

After that the call inside your validator method becomes a bit cleaner.

```
boolean isValid(Entry entry, Context context) {
    boolean valid = true;
    valid &= contextualEquals(entry.fieldA, this.fieldA, context.fieldA, fieldA.matchingMode);
    valid &= contextualEquals(entry.fieldB, this.fieldB, context.fieldB, fieldB.matchingMode);
    return valid;
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
You can expand on this answer with a Field enum:

```
enum Fields {
    FIELD_A, FIELD_B;
}
```

Your context is then just more or less a Map:

```
class Validator {
    // if you stick with context, this should be a context then...
    Map<Fields, Object> matchingMode = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        matchingMode.put(Fields.FIELD_A, 123);
    }

    boolean isValid(Entry entry, Map<Fields, Object> context) {
        boolean valid = true;
        valid &= contextualEquals(entry.fieldA, Fields.FIELD_A, context, matchingMode);
        valid &= contextualEquals(entry.fieldB, Fields.FIELD_B, context, matchingMode);
        return valid;
    }


    <T> boolean contextualEquals(T entryValue, Fields field, Map<> context, Map<> matchingMode) {
        if (matchingMode.containsKey(field)) {
            return Objects.equals(entryValue, matchingMode.get(field));
        }
        return Objects.equals(entryValue, context.get(field));
    }
}
```

with that you define the real field only once in Entry and connect the field once in the Validator to its enum.

Comment: This indeed makes the code look prettier, as it reduces the bulk of duplicate code. But can't we kill the devil from its roots and remove the need for duplicate code altogether?

Comment: @fzwd The questions in the edit clarified it a bit for me, maybe this edit makes you happier :)

Comment: Interesting idea! I would try and come up with a solution that encapsulates all the dirty work for field management

Answer (score 1):

First some thoughts:

- In Java you can't make a loop over fields as in JavaScript. It is not entirely impossible (you can play with reflection) but usually not a good choice.
- If you are building a production code maybe you could use some third party tools (maybe from Apache or Spring) which can help with your goal. As you didn't mention them I didn't use them.
- The bigger picture and flow of your application may vary the best answer.

So my suggestion:

Assume you have three fields to validate:

```
Type1 field1
Type2 field2
Type3 field3
```

I would create a Validator class:

Edit due to comments (Thanks for **Absurd-Mind**):

```
class Validator{
  public final Optional<Type1> optionalField1;
  public final Optional<Type2> optionalField2;
  public final Optional<Type3> optionalField3;

  public Validator(Optional<Type1> optionalField1,
                   Optional<Type2> optionalField2,
                   Optional<Type3> optionalField3){
    this.optionalField1 = optionalField1;
    this.optionalField2 = optionalField2;
    this.optionalField3 = optionalField3;
  }

  public boolean isValid(Entry entry, Context context){
     boolean answer = true;
     answer &= entry.field1.equals(optionalField1.orElse(context.field1));
     answer &= entry.field2.equals(optionalField2.orElse(context.field2));
     answer &= entry.field3.equals(optionalField3.orElse(context.field3));
     return answer;
 }
```

In this case, you can indicate the proper way of validation with the presence of Optional. If you are looking for a design pattern I could recommend a builder for the validator.

**Solution two:**

If you would like to keep clean your validation class you can use the following pattern:

Create an interface:

```
interface Rule{
  boolean check(Entry entry, Context context);
}
```

The validator class:

```
class Validator{
 List<Rule> rules = new ArrayList<>();

 public boolean validate(Entry entry, Context context){
   boolean answer = true;
   for(Rule rule : rules){
        answer &= rule.check(entry,context);
   }
   return answer;
 }

 public void addRule(Rule rule){
     rules.add(rule);
 }
}
```

Now you will have plenty of Rule implementations but your validation class will be clean and straightforward. Before use, you have to populate the right rules to the validation class. In a rule, you can specify which field should be checked against which value (own property or context property).

Comment: You could totally just replace the Optionals with null values as you gain no benefits by using them. Or atleast use them! `answer &= entry.field1.equals(optionalField1.orElse(context.field1));`

Comment: This code basically replaces `MatchingMode` checks with `isPresent` checks from the original (current) code, but still does not 'feel' right. For every field that is added/removed, several methods from 3 classes need to be edited. The validator class already uses a builder, since the number of fields to be set are otherwise overwhelming

Comment: When combined with a factory class for Rule, this could be a very clean solution!